# Height not set if div is made absolute, height gets 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[A Collection Of Page Transitions Example (Codrops)](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/07/a-collection-of-page-transitions/)

I've read this tutorial to make page transitions, but instead of transitioning the whole page i need to transition a division inside the body

the abstract of my code is as follows:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div id="main-body" class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div id="milestone-container" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row center-block">
                <!-- Some of the website defaults -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form id="store-form-parent" class="col-md-12 form-horizontal">
            <div id="store-form" class="row">
                <div class="page page-1">
                    <div class="form-1 horizontally-padded">
                        <!-- Page 1 Content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="page page-2">
                    <div class="form-1 horizontally-padded">
                        <!-- Page 2 Content -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Some Modals for the page-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="capture-modal">
                <!-- modal content -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="font-style-modal">
                <!-- modal content -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="face-style-modal">
                <!-- Modal content -->
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"> </div>
```

What changes have i done in my code:

1. I have removed -pt- from every classnames from the code example in
   the link
2. Made **form.store-form-parent** relative, **div.store-form** relative and **div.page** absolute
3. I am using Bootstrap Framework.

Now the problem is:

> **div.page** if set to **absolute** loses it's **height**.(I need it to be absolute for proper page transition effects)

Some points that i have tried:

> 1. Make **div.page** { top, bottom, right, left = 0 }, as I've read from somewhere that putting values of these keys to 0, gives absolute div it's height (as absolute div have their own layout context)
> 2. Giving parent div, i.e., **div.store-form,** some height does makes my problem solve, but my **each page has different amount of content and thus have different sizes**, so I can't use this solution.
> 3. Making **div.page** as relative is also not a feasible solution..
> 4. I don't want to use javascript for dynamically setting parent divs height.

What I need:

> I think that absolute divs cannot be used on dynamic sized divs for these types of transition effects, so please either provide me with a proper page transition example suitable with my condition(which is very much appreciated), or , can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code

**The Webpage as needed**
 [image: Website as needed]

**The Webpage that i'm getting (with 0 height)** 
[image: Website that i get (with error)]

[my css file (a short snippet) which is creating the problem](http://pastebin.com/8zF4sEQw)

Comment: Please clearly state your problem: What behavior are you seeing, and what are you expecting. Prepare an example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Absolutely positioned elements work just fine with dynamically sized elements, so we need more to go on.

Comment: Without seeing your CSS we would be unable to provide any suggestions.

Comment: i did try to make an example, but it's a very long code.. but the main problem is that when i converted all my code to an example, absolute div got it's height back. I don't understand what the problem is. I'm using php framework to dynamically load pages, would that be any help. or should i still post my example. the css is generated using less so all my css get's attached to html file only, making it a 5000 lines of code. I'm providing images related to my problem. Please help me here!!